# Multiple regex replacements in a loop do not work

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm attempting to replace URL's and @username mentions of twitter data using Python's regular expression and a for loop.

```
d = df['text']
for i, e in enumerate(d):
    d[i] = re.sub('((www.\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL', e)
    d[i] = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', e)
```

The problem is that the for loop only works for the second line of regex code ('AT_USER'). I want to replace the URL AND @username mentions. I was thinking of making two separate for loops for each but surely there's a more effective way?

Comment: `d[i] = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', e)` => `d[i] = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', d[i])` or your first line has no effect

Comment: Why are you using pandas and not using `str.replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue with your code as of now is here -

```
#                                  vvv
d[i] = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', e)
```

You should be passing `d[i]` instead of `e`. The fact that you pass `e` means you *overwrite* the result of the first replacement. Change it, and it should work.

---

You're using pandas. It's time to ditch the loop. First, initialise a dictionary of regex-replacement pairs -

```
p_dict = {r'((www.\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))' : 'URL', r'@[^\s]+' : 'AT_USER'}
```

Now, pass this to `df.replace` with the `regex` switch -

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(p_dict, regex=True)
```

Here's a little example with some dummy data -

```
s

0    12.2
1    12.5
2    12.6
3    15.1
4    15.3
5    15.0
dtype: object

s[0]   
Out[190]: '12.2'   # a string

p_dict = {'\d' : '<DIGIT>', '\.' : '<DOT>'}

s.replace(p_dict, regex=True)

0    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
1    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
2    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
3    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
4    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
5    <DIGIT><DIGIT><DOT><DIGIT>
dtype: object
```

Comment: hey stop bragging with your rep cap hat :) You could've explained the error the OP had in the first place (see my comment)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh, I see what you mean. ;-) Sure, will update!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Good job, thank you for not only explaining my error but also providing an answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy coding.